# Openshift build fails only in a specific project (with meteor error)

Tags: docker, meteor, build, openshift, openshift-enterprise

Using Openshift 4.6.
I'm trying to build an image with a buildConfig, a docker strategy from a binary source (local directory). The buildConfig is generated with the command:

```
oc new-build . name=build-name --strategy=docker --to=registry-url/image-name:tag --push-secret=secret-name --to-docker.
```

The build is started with the command:

```
oc start-build build-name --from-dir=. --wait --follow
```

The base image is pulled properly and the local Dockerfile starts executing. The dockerfile involves usage of meteor command, and it's okay as the base image contains meteor in /root directory and I'm running everything with `--allow-superuser`.
When running any meteor command (even --version), the build fails with:

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1jauib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57-glibc/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1jauib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1jauib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/build

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Error: Missing binary. See message above.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1jauib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
```

The file fibers.node definitely exists, as when I run in the Dockerfile `echo $(ls -la )` it prints `fibers.node`.
To complicate things more, this problem only occurs when building in a specific project (namespace). When running the same buildConfig, with same secrets, in different projects it works well. Unfortunately, I need this project.

What can be the cause of faulty build in a specific namespace? Otherwise, there are no problen with it and it has more than sufficient resources and limits

Comment: Is anything about this project different from the one where it works? eg can you compare them with `oc describe project` ?

Comment: Comparison of the results of oc describe project shows same details, except slightly higher resources for the problematic project, though both are nowhere near their limits. The problematic project is the one where our testing environment is, so there are additional imageStreams, buildConfigs and other oc objects there (though no other builds).